# Send and read InputOutput parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

I have stored procedure in my SQL Server database that takes few parameters of which one is input and output parameter.

This is the code I am using:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(globals))
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("addNewOrder", sqlConnection))
{
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SomeDataA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _someDataA;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SomeDataB", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _someDataB;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SomeDataC", SqlDbType.Float).Value = _someDataC;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@InputAndOutput", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=_inputAndOutput; 
    sqlCommand.Parameters["@InputAndOutput"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

    using (var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(sqlCommand.Parameters["@InputAndOutput"].Value))
            {
                _inputAndOutput = sqlCommand.Parameters["@InputAndOutput"].Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _inputAndOutput = "N/A";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exx.Message);
        }
    }

    return _inputAndOutput;
}
```

In SQL Server, in the stored procedure, the parameter `@InputAndOutput` is declared as `@InputAndOutput varchar(36) = NULL OUTPUT`.

When the stored procedure receives data, it will insert into database and return `Uniqueidentifier` in that `@InputAndOutput` parameter.

This is all working  if I am not sending anything with `@InputAndOutput`.

For example this will work just fine:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@InputAndOutput", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Problem is when I send 1 character to stored procedure it will return only 1 character of that 36 char guid. If I send 2, it will return 2 and so on...

Example:

```
_inputAndOutput= "2" -> SP
(SP insert into DB, and returns "D00896A4-69D5-4FAC-B249-9409A643966A") -> _inputAndOutput
_inputAndOutput = "D"
```

In case when I send 22, it will receive "D0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the size of the parameter when you declare  it

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@InputAndOutput", SqlDbType.VarChar,36).Value=_inputAndOutput;
```

Without it the engine will create a parameter big just enough to contain your input value and this size is not changed by the Sql engine to accomodate your longer return value.